# Wrong pivot point of parent / wrong scale of children

Tags: unity, rotation, maya, scale

I'm trying to make two objects, in is an intact glass, the other one is the glass but shattered.

So for the shattered glass, in Maya I make a Plane, cut it with the multi-cut tool, extrude the faces, select the object and then separate. So I have every single piece of the glass as a single object. After that, I select them all, Modify->Center Pivot.

Now when I import this into unity, this is where the problems arrive.

- When I rotate the native parent object, which holds all the glass pieces, it looks right:

[Native Parent Rotation](https://giphy.com/gifs/26AHRlUUDnGkIXpde)

- When I rotate all the child glass pieces, the distort some weird way, the scaling is really off on one axis and they appear very thin:

[Native Child Rotation](https://giphy.com/gifs/26AHGloJHr9cUCiBO)

- Now, when I create a new empty GameObject on root level, and simply add all the children glass pieces to this object, they rotate just fine and have the right scaling:

[New Parent - Child Rotation](https://giphy.com/gifs/3o6ozhft9cpsLVohdC)

- But now, when I rotate the parent, the pivot point seems to be completely off:

[New Parent - Parent Rotation](https://giphy.com/gifs/xT1XGPALOkRkvumkVi)

The rotation I make is a simple `gameObject.transform.Rotate (Vector3.left);`

How can I achieve the correct pivot point for the parent, and avoid the weird scaling issues on the children? I need to be precise of course, because the shattered parent object is supposed to replace the intact glass object 1:1 after a collision.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally fixed it after several hours.

Problem was, my parent plane in Maya was set to something like 6,3 / 2,1 / 3,1. So this was the scaling the object always got imported into Unity, which messed up its space / pivot points.

In Maya I now just used `Modify->Freeze Transformations` on the Plane, to normalize it to 1 / 1 / 1. After that I had to re-reset my pivot points on my glass pieces (select all, `Modify->Center Pivot`.

Now all rotates around the correct pivot points and scales the way it's supposed to.